# Поиск по key в Dictionary<string,string,string> C#

Tags: c#, коллекции, словари

Есть словарь Dictionary Украинских слов в котором хранятся перевод на Английском и Русском языке.
Нужно реализовать метод который бы выводил к выбранному Укр. слову перевод на Русском или Англ.
Вот словарь сделал чтобы 2 значения можно было впихивать к ключу, а вот затем поиск осуществить по ключу проблема.

```
   class DictionaryUkrEngRus : Dictionary<string, MyValue>
        {
            public void Add(string key, string value1, string value2)
            {
                MyValue val;
                val.EngValue = value1;
                val.RusValue = value2;
                this.Add(key, val);
            }
    
            public void TranslateToEng(string value)
            { 
           
            }
    
            public void TranslateToRus(string value)
            { 
            
            }
        }
    
        public struct MyValue
        {
            public string EngValue;
            public string RusValue;
        }

class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var dict = new DictionaryUkrEngRus();
            dict.Add("Прапор" , "Флаг", "Flag");
            dict.Add("Тисяча", "Тысяча", "One thousand");
            dict.Add("Келих", "Бокал", "Glass");
            dict.TranslateToEng("Тисяча");
            dict.TranslateToRus("Келих");
        }
    }
```

Comment: `this[value]` вернет твой `MyValue` для этого ключа

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Вроде-как никакой особой магии не требуется

```cs
public string TranslateToEng(string key)
{ 
    return this[key].EngValue;
}
    
public string TranslateToRus(string key)
{ 
    return this[key].RusValue;
}
```

Проверить можно так

```cs
Console.WriteLine(dict.TranslateToEng("Тисяча"));
Console.WriteLine(dict.TranslateToRus("Келих"));
```

Comment: понял спасибо)) была мысль об этом , но думал this не проканает так как this покажет только на последний добавленный элемент, к вечеру видимо голова уже не особо думает)